# Does the EMR delete and update DynamoDB and S3 records

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

Does the EMR servers allow delete and update DynamoDB records/files, I've read that it only allow Read and Analyze through Elastic map reduce (EMR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to DynamoDB from EMR using Hive. Try defining a table as follows and then run any valid INSERT statement.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dyndb_table_name(
  [col_name] [type],
  ...
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "dynamodb.table.name" = "[table_name]",
  "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "[local_name:dyndb_name],..."
);
```

Also, read the AWS documentation on this at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html